# Flatten 2d array and cast all string values to int

Tags: php, arrays, merge, casting, flatten

How should I make this array value that is in string form

```
Array
(
    [0] => ["1","2"]
    [1] => ["5"]
)
```

into int form

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
)
```

Is it complicated? Anyone can help?

Comment: So just to be clear: Is your input: `Array( ...)` a string or are you just talking about the values inside the array?

Comment: What have you tried? Few lines of PHP will do

Comment: I guess `array_map('intval', $array)` will help here.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: you want like this:- https://eval.in/805641

Comment: hmm.. just the value inside the array now is currently in `string`. I wanted to convert it to `int` and separate it

Comment: @ron Okay, so then you know that php is dynamically typed and when your string is in a numerical context it will automatically get converted to a int. So for what exactly do you then want to convert them to integers? From your expected output you seem to also want to flatten the array to a single dimensional array, right?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `array_map` to parse string to int and `array_reduce` with `array_merge` to join the arrays

```
$data = Array(["1","2"],["5"]);
$result = array_map('intval', array_reduce($data, 'array_merge', array()));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This answer has a greater time complexity than other answers on this page because it is making 1 `array_reduce()` call which makes 2 `array_merge()` calls, then after flattening the structure it makes 1 `array_map()` call to make 3 `intval()` calls.  Other answers make zero or one functional call to perform the whole task.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$array = [
    ["1", "2"],
    ["5"],
];

$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $rowArr) {
    foreach ($rowArr as $str) {
        $newArray[] = intval($str);
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

This returns:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 5
```

This works by iterating `$array`, then iterating `$array`'s child elements (`$rowArr`) and adding each element to `$newArray` after running `intval` on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_reduce` (https://3v4l.org/H4eIV)

```
$a = Array
(
    0=> ["1","2"],
    1=> ["5"]
);
$r = array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array());
var_export($r);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '2',
  2 => '5',
)
```

Comment: This answer is only doing half of the required task.  The asker wishes for the values to be explicitly cast as int-type instead of string-type.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to loop through the two layers of your array.

```
$input=[["1","2"],["5"]];

foreach($input as $a){
    foreach($a as $v){
        $result[]=+$v;  // make integer
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: create a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) that [casts](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) variables to ints and appends them to an array.

```
$appendInt = function($x) use (&$result) { $result[] = (int) $x; };
//    reference to result array^  append to result^      ^cast to int
```

Apply it to every element of your multidimensional array with [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

```
array_walk_recursive($your_array, $appendInt);
```

The flat array of ints will be in the `$result` variable.